# Using %in% operator on data.table column

Tags: r, data.table

With usual `data.frame` you can do something like this:

```
head(mtcars[, 2]) %in% 6
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

How can I do the same thing with `data.table`? I tried something like this, didn't work:

```
as.data.table(mtcars)[, 2] %in% 4
[1] FALSE
```

There is always a way of `as.data.frame(myDT)` of course, but it doesn't seem elegant.

Comment: Use the `[[` to subset as a vector.  `[,2]`  is still a data.table with one column.  Instead `as.data.table(mtcars)[[2]] %in% 4`  It is one of the difference with `data.frame`, and `data.table/tibble`

Comment: Thanks, @akrun! I thought there would be something like `drop` option in data.frame for data.tables

Comment: For subsetting columns, there is `with = FALSE`

Comment: Yeah, I tried it before posting here like this `mtcars[, "mpg", with = FALSE]`, but it didn't subset a vector as was needed. Anyways you helped me. Should I close the question? I'd accept the answer if you post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `data.table/tibble/data_frame` etc, the `[,columnindex]` for a single column will still return a `data.table/tibble/data_frame`.  We need to either use `$` or `[[` to return a `vector` and `%in%` works on `vector`

```
as.data.table(mtcars)[[2]] %in% 4
```